# sp_OACreate script returns Null value from API fetch? The API works well in a html file

Tags: sql-server, scripting, ole-automation, external-scripts

I am trying to create a script in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to fetch the current exchange rate from an API and update a database. I am told it is not posisble and common to do this.

```
-- Change the database context
USE lndb;

-- Declare variables
DECLARE @url NVARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @responseText NVARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE @exchangeRate DECIMAL(10, 6);

-- Set the API URL
SET @url = 'https://www.banxico.org.mx/SieAPIRest/service/v1/series/SF43718/datos/oportuno?token=734b37b3a5099a9d2d39d06478d47e359a9568cd6693116d95b710e6b8be0008';

-- Make HTTP request and store the response
EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @responseText OUTPUT;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @responseText, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @url, false;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @responseText, 'send';
EXEC sp_OAMethod @responseText, 'responseText', @exchangeRate OUTPUT;
EXEC sp_OADestroy @responseText;

-- Convert the response to a decimal
SET @exchangeRate = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 6), @exchangeRate);
SELECT @exchangeRate

-- Update the teimcs008401 table in the dbo schema
INSERT INTO dbo.teimcs008401 (t_bcur, t_ccur, t_rate, t_stdt, t_Refcntd, t_Refcntu)
VALUES ('MXP', 'USD', @exchangeRate, GETDATE(), '0', '0');

-- Display the updated exchange rate
SELECT * FROM dbo.teimcs008401;
```

[image: Result from SELECT @exchangeRate]

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend for you to instead either write a small application to do this for you or, in the worst case, use CLR stored procedures. sp_OA* methods are terrible. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/333366/huge-preemptive-os-getprocaddress-waits-from-sp-oamethod-how-to-debug

Comment: ^Seconded CLR **if** this **needs** to run directly in the database.

Comment: @J.D What does an example of a CLR looks like?

Comment: @LuisAvalos I can't really explain an example in a comment, but start with [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/common-language-runtime-integration-overview?view=sql-server-ver16). In short, CLR allows you to compile C# code down to a module that can be loaded into the SQL Server instance, and then executed by SQL code. The docs even say "*code for accessing external resources (servers, web services, databases)*".

Comment: Consider a simple PowerShell script (perhaps scheduled via SQL Agent job) for this task. This isn't a job for T-SQL.

Comment: Check the value of `@exchangeRate` before you run the `SET`. I find the coercion questionable.

Comment: This is about 3 lines of Powershell, and will do it much better.